# How to display flatlist using LongListSelector phone control of WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

In **toolkit** **LongListSelector**, there used to be a property **IsFlatList** which needed to be set to true to display flat list without any grouping. But in the **LongListSelector** provided in phone control, this property is missing. Here is what I am doing

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="myList"  IsGroupingEnabled="False" LayoutMode="List" ItemsSource="{Binding Source ={StaticResource SortedList} }" CacheMode="BitmapCache"  >
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <components:MyControl  CacheMode="BitmapCache" MyItem="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

If I change the control to ListBox and remove LongListSelector specific property then it display my list.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?
I am following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)(Remarks) documentation of LongListSelector

Answer (score 3):

In the Windows Phone 8 Version of the LongListSelector setting LayoutMode to List and IsGroupingEnabled to false should display your databound data as a flat list like in the WP7 Toolkit version of the control.

For example,

Given an Entity class

```
public class Entity
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Info
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

All I need to do is create an ObservableCollection of Entity on my page and bind it to the itemsource of my LongListSelector (named list).

```
ObservableCollection<Entity> data = new ObservableCollection<Entity>();
list.ItemsSourdce = data;
```

Then I create the entities and add them to the collection.

Here is the XAML for my LongListSelector:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:LongListSelector Name="list" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="609" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" LayoutMode="List" IsGroupingEnabled="False" >
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"  Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Info}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Hmmmmmmm. After spending several hours playing with LongListSelector in WP8 and not having my data display I changed Grouping enabled to false and voilà the data appeared! Maybe something for other WP8 (XAML?) noobs to consider. I am setting ItemSources in code behind. Must be how I have structured data which is just a List<> of simple objects with no grouping.

Comment: I showed in my example that isGroupingEnabled must be set to false if you want a normal "list" and not a grouped list.

Comment: @SleepyBoBos, it says to do just that in the first sentence of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

LayoutMode ="List" that's all you need.